# How can I pass multiple values to a table-valued parameter?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have the following code that passes a value into a function via a table-valued parameter that is then used in a `WHERE` clause using a `IN` operator:

```
drop table if exists mytbl;
create table mytbl (i int);
DO $$
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT   * FROM  pg_type t WHERE t.typname = 'tp') THEN
        CREATE TYPE tp AS (i int);
    END IF;
END$$;
insert into mytbl (i) values (1),(2),(3);
DROP FUNCTION public.filterer(tp);
CREATE FUNCTION filterer(
    _filter tp
)
RETURNS TABLE(i_ret int)
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    RETURN  QUERY   SELECT  i 
                    FROM    mytbl
                    WHERE   row(i) IN (_filter);
END;
$BODY$;

select * from filterer(row(1));
```

I'm using `row()` to define a value to be passed however what I want to do is pass multiple values, essentially I want to pass a list. How can  I do that?

Comment: You can use an array

Comment: ok. How do I do that?

Comment: Attention - these simple (dynamic) function's query wrappers is best way, how to kill performance. It can work if it is used directly from last point - but can be terrible, if you use it from some complex other SQL. The function is black box for optimizer. So if you can, don't wrap simple queries

Comment: Yes I realise that. In my case its necessary to encapsulate some complicated logic and the calling application will simply be selecting the data, not joining it to anything.

Answer (score 0):

for example:

```
t=# create or replace function fn (a variadic int[]) returns table(i int, c text)as $$
begin
return query select *,chr(100+g) from generate_series(1,9) g where g = any(a);
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION
```

and execution:

```
t=# select * from fn(4,5,8);
 i | c
---+---
 4 | h
 5 | i
 8 | l
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks, although that won't for my my actual situation because in reality the function has numerous table-valued parameters, and I need the ability to pass multiple values for each.